# Merge two sorted array in one and sort it in javaScript. But sort() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sorting

My code is :

```js
arr1=[2,6,8,56,78,99,100];
arr2=[1,4,6,8,9,99];
arr3=arr1.concat(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
arr3.sort()
console.log(arr3);
```

But this sort() function gives wrong result. I don't understand why it is giving that result?
It should have sorted arr3.

Comment: It *did* sort the array; it just compared the values as if they were strings, not by their numeric values.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding. `Array.sort` does not sort numerical, but alphabetical.

You can use this, however:

```
Array.sort((a, b)  => { return a - b; });
```

Comment: Good answer. fyi - you don't need the curlies or the `return` keyword as you are only returning a single value from a single expression. (`.sort((a,b)=>a-b);`) It would also be better to put a working example into a stackblitz so the OP has confidence in your answer.